# How to check if old model or schema exists in mongoose mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there any way to identify whether schema or model is old in mongoose or mongoDB.

for Ex:

I have a schema like this

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
   Addresfrom: {
     type: Number,
     unique: true
   },
   Addressto: {
     type: Number,
     unique: true
   }
})
```

I have to drop the indexes if the schema or model is old.

Please suggest any ideas !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you checked [mongoose-history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-history). you may download that plugin. and either use it or study it.